# Geoprocessing in 3D

Tags: geoprocessing, 3d, hydrology

I am looking for some advice regarding suitable software for geoprocessing in three dimensions. Specifically, I need to regularly undertake the following tasks:

- Intersect a line with a surface and output the XYZ value of the point
- Intersect a surface with a surface and return a 3D polyline
- Clip a solid to a surface

What software do others in the community use for such tasks?

I am especially interested in software that others have used successfully in the resources industries, particularly for hydrological and geotechnical work.

Comment: This is a bit broad for a question.  Try to draw more specific answers. It could turn into a community wiki if not.

Comment: I appreciate the advice Brad, but not sure how much more specific I can be. I've already listed the specific geoprocessing tasks that I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: subjective questions are often removed or tagged as community wiki. see the help.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask  re-wording the question so you ask specific questions and not a general how does everyone do it.

Comment: I think this looks like three questions in one Question so probably best to focus this question on the most important Geoprocessing task first and then research/ask the others separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need GMT (http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/) (free). Even though it's a bit harder to work with at the beginning, much of what you need is possible (even though I've never tried it myself). Oasis montaj (http://www.geosoft.com/products/oasis-montaj) as well as ArcGis may be more friendly because of their interactive functionality, but they are not free (quite expensive actually).

I've read time ago that QGis is a good choice for such tasks, somewhere in Internet I found good examples about the both topics you're asking, however I don't have those links but sure you can find them easily with the good Google.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Gery - I will check out the GMT resource you recommend. Also, I'm a big fan of QGIS, but was unaware of its ability to perform geoprocessing tasks in three dimensions. I'll do a little more research into this.